# Does the 6th April 2023 date for reduced CGT personal allowance apply to date of sale, or exchange of contracts?

Tags: england-and-wales, tax-law, rental-property, real-estate

We are selling a rental property and as such Capital Gains Tax (CGT) applies on profits. [On 6th April 2023, the personal CGT allowance is being reduced from £12,300 to £6000](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/reducing-the-annual-exempt-amount-for-capital-gains-tax/capital-gains-tax-annual-exempt-amount).

Our sale is likely to complete around this date and with two owners, that means we potentially stand to pay CGT on an additional £12,600.

Somebody told me that the key factor in the date cut-off is when contracts are exchanged for the sale, rather than when the sale is completed. But I cannot find any information supporting or rejecting this claim. Can anyone give an evidence-based answer either way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the date of exchange, referred to as the "disposal date".

See the [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/capital-gains-tax) guidance:

> Capital Gains Tax is a tax on the profit when you sell (or ‘dispose of’) something (an ‘asset’) that’s increased in value.

And the HMRC [Capital Gains Manual](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/capital-gains-manual/cg-app18-230):

> *What date did you exchange contracts?*
>
> This is the disposal date. The contract exchange date is usually when the buyer and seller exchange contracts and is usually when the new owner pays a deposit.
>
> The tax year of exchange is the tax year that the disposal is chargeable in, even if completion of the contract occurs in a later tax year.